# Generate a google map link with directions using waypoints (latitude and longitude)

Tags: html, google-maps

I'm trying to create a google map link that will redirect to a map with directions. I will pass the waypoints in the link.

Here is the sample link that it is currently producing

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=12.909227,77.6343&destination=12.909228,77.6343&travelmode=driving&waypoints=12.909188,77.6323,12.91044,77.632507,12.911389,77.632912

instead of using the full address for waypoints used latitude longitude

Comment: What is the problem with the provided link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode):

> Multiple waypoints can be specified by using the pipe character (|) to separate places (e.g. Berlin,Germany|Paris,France). You can specify up to 20 waypoints. Each waypoint can be either a place name, address or place ID.

The request (currently) accepts comma separated coordinates as well.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=12.909227,77.6343&destination=12.909228,77.6343&travelmode=driving&waypoints=12.909188,77.6323|12.91044,77.632507|12.911389,77.632912
```

[link](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=12.909227,77.6343&destination=12.909228,77.6343&travelmode=driving&waypoints=12.909188,77.6323|12.91044,77.632507|12.911389,77.632912)